# R notebook kernel dies when interrupted in Data Science Experience

Tags: r, jupyter, data-science-experience

I'm using R notebooks on Data Science Experience, backed by an Apache Spark service. When I select "Kernel -> Interrupt" while executing a long-running code block (for example: `Sys.sleep(8)`), everything works as expected. The cell execution stops, the kernel returns to idle state.

But when I select "Kernel -> Interrupt" while the kernel is idle, or when the cell execution just completes as I am interrupting it, the kernel dies. There is a warning dialog that the kernel will restart automatically, and all data in memory is lost. In the log file, I can later see:

`Execution halted
17/12/27 03:58:43 INFO apache.spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook`

Can someone explain this behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a peculiarity of the R kernel, and not specific to Data Science Experience. There is a long-standing [bug report](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/245), and a corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/pull/246) which never got merged.

Until this has been resolved in the code base of the R kernel, and Data Science Experience has installed a version including the fix, it's better not to try interrupting the R kernel there.